# Controlling IP Cameras with Tkinter Buttons (Python)

Tags: python, tkinter, camera, ip, controls

I have been trying to create a GUI with tkinter to control 4 IP cameras with Python. At first I thought it's because I didn't have the right IP or Ports but I used packet sender to check it out. I'm confused on why the program won't work when I try to use it in Python 2.7. Below is the code for one of my cameras - left camera, it is a PTZoptics camera. The camera and the computers are all connected on one network via ethernet. Currently, I am currently controlling them with an IP joystick.

```
import socket
import tkinter as tk


class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.up = tk.Button(self, text="LEFT CAMERA UP")

        self.down = tk.Button(self, text="LEFT CAMERA DOWN")

        self.left = tk.Button(self, text="LEFT CAMERA LEFT")

        self.right = tk.Button(self, text="LEFT CAMERA RIGHT")

        self.up.pack(side="top")

        self.down.pack(side="bottom")

        self.left.pack(side="left")

        self.right.pack(side="right")

        self.up.bind("<ButtonPress>", self.on_LCup)
        self.up.bind("<ButtonRelease>", self.on_LCrelease)

        self.down.bind("<ButtonPress>", self.on_LCdown)
        self.down.bind("<ButtonRelease>", self.on_LCrelease)

        self.left.bind("<ButtonPress>", self.on_LCleft)
        self.left.bind("<ButtonRelease>", self.on_LCrelease)

        self.right.bind("<ButtonPress>", self.on_LCright)
        self.right.bind("<ButtonRelease>", self.on_LCrelease)

    def on_LCup(self, event):
        LeftHost = '10.30.1.41'
        port1 = 5678

        LC = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        LC.connect((LeftHost, port1))
        LC.send("81 01 06 01 08 08 03 01 FF")

    def on_LCdown(self, event):
        LeftHost = '10.30.1.41'
        port1 = 5678

        LC = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        LC.connect((LeftHost, port1))
        LC.send("81 01 06 01 08 08 03 02 FF")


    def on_LCleft(self, event):
        LeftHost = '10.30.1.41'
        port1 = 5678

        LC = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        LC.connect((LeftHost, port1))
        LC.send("81 01 06 01 08 08 01 03 FF")

    def on_LCright(self, event):
        LeftHost = '10.30.1.41'
        port1 = 5678

        LC = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        LC.connect((LeftHost, port1))
        LC.send("81 01 06 01 08 08 02 03 FF")

    def on_LCrelease(self, event):
        LeftHost = '10.30.1.41'
        port1 = 5678

        LC = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        LC.connect((LeftHost, port1))
        LC.send("81 01 06 01 08 08 03 03 FF")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What does this code do? Is the camera turning the wrong way? Is the wrong camera turning the right way? Does the program crash? Something else?

Comment: This code opens up a window showing four buttons (up, down, left and right). The button's don't do anything. There's no error message, however, I tested the button with a "button pressed" message before putting in IP commands and that worked. My main problem is trying to get the VISCA commands to the cameras via IP, I can't even get it to work in the python terminal.

Comment: Under Python 2, `Tkinter` should be used instead of `tkinter`.  I wonder why your code runs with Python 2.

Comment: I think that you have sent incorrect message to the camera, for example, `"81 01 06 01 08 08 03 01 FF"` should be `b"\x81\x01\x06\x01\x08\x08\x03\x01\xFF"` instead.

Comment: Tried that, no dice.

Comment: Try reading the response (ACK) from the IP cam after sending the command.

Comment: After sending the the ack command I didn't receive anything back. So that means nothing is being sent?

Comment: Try something like `LC.send(bytes([0x81, 0x01, 0x06, 0x01, 0x08, 0x08, 0x03, 0x01, 0xFF]))` instead of sending string, and then try to read the response.

Comment: After doing that I got a syntax error. It wouldn't accept the commas.

Answer (score 0):

add --> bytes.fromhex in LC.send::
LC.send(bytes.fromhex("81 01 06 01 08 08 03 03 FF"))

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).